# How do I retrieve a certifcate from a https webserver and check if it's valid and/or self-signed

Tags: javascript, https, certificate, nativescript

A webview in nativescript does not work with self-signed certificates, unless the user has added them to the device's user certificates.

I would like to simplify the process for the user by getting the certificate from the server, check if something needs to be done, and guide the user through the necessary steps if so.

I've found the `node-forge` module which looks promising, but so far I haven't managed to load a certificate from a server.

Comment: You can implement a custom WebViewClient and implement [onReceivedSslError](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onReceivedSslError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.SslErrorHandler,%20android.net.http.SslError)) which gives you access to [SslCertificate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/SslError#getCertificate()) which you can validate and proceed / cancel the request.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I already have been looking at that.

But I would like to avoid modifying the nativescript platform resources, and I'd like to also make https-requests outside the webview in the nativescript app.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your q, I would just use OpenSSL from the command-line. For example, the following:

openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.microsoft.com:443

Will fetch the certs in the chain and you can look to see if they match what you expect. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but since my target environment is a `nativescript` application, I do not have `openssl` available. Unless I missed that...